# How do I spawn (possibly) blocking async tasks in tokio?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

When a request comes in, I have to process data in a highly parallelizable way.  The processing is a mix of some CPU-intensive work (1ms bursts), and potentially needing a blocking web request (library out of my control).  The function is exposed to me as a sync function, but uses block_in_place() under the hood when blocking.

Say I have the following example:

```
async fn handle_request(data: &Bytes) {
    let mut results = vec![];
    for i in 0..1000 {
      let processed = do_heavy_calc_that_might_block(data, i); <-- this possibly needs to do a blocking web request, uses block_in_place when it does
      let result = do_something_with_res(processed).await;
      results.push(result);
    }
    results
  }
```

I'd love to to use either `tokio::task::spawn()` or `spawn_blocking()`, but both have problems in testing.  If I use `spawn` with something like:

```
  async fn handle_request(data: &Bytes) {
    let mut tasks = vec![];
    for i in 0..1000 {
      tasks.push(tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        let processed = do_heavy_calc_that_might_block(data, i);
        let result = do_something_with_res(processed).await;
        result
      }));
    }
    let results =  futures_util::future::join_all(tasks).await;
    results
  }
```

When do_heavy_calc runs, if too many of the chunks need to block, they `block_in_place()`, and the runtime gets starved, with nothing ever completing.

If I switch to `spawn_blocking` instead, I can't pass it an async function, so the `do_something_with_res` can't `.await`.  Obviously I can return the processed data out of the task and do the `do_something_with_res` after the loop, but the actual code in the task goes back and forth between block/async/block/async multiple times.  So was looking for something more general.

I've tried using Rayon instead of within tokio, but I end up not parallelizing as far as I'd like.  Since the blocking calls can take time, they can clog up the thread pool as well, and since they're mixed in with async calls, would be nice to take advantage of the tokio runtime I'm already working within...

Answer (score 1):

The regular Tokio worker thread pool, and Rayon's thread pool, are both designed around the assumption that each task they run is either busy using the CPU, or yielding. If you put blocking-on-network tasks on *either* of them, you're going to get poor performance. You need to use something *other* than a thread pool that has been sized for CPU parallelism.

[`spawn_blocking()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) is a good way to do that. In order to interact with async code from within the blocking task, you can call [`Handle::block_on()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.block_on).

Note that the number of [`max_blocking_threads`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.max_blocking_threads) also affects how your `spawn_blocking` tasks execute. The default is 512, so you're unlikely to hit it unless you've got a *lot* of work to do, but if it does come up, you might want to impose an explicit limit in your application logic, because tasks waiting to run still take up memory, network servers may not appreciate too many incoming connections, and you've only got so many CPU cores anyway — so at that point you may find that overall throughput is improved by intentionally queueing things within your application logic rather than throwing everything you've got at Tokio.

Comment: Understood on the max cpu contention issue.  Just in a weird spot with the underlying code blocking.  I can't easily run it within tokio/rayons normal threadpool, since very quickly I block and have a ton of tasks that _could_ run, but all the threads are blocked on IO (like you mentioned).  `spawn_blocking` looks like the right choice, was just hoping there was a way to essentially pass it an async, so it could be run on the larger threadpool, but still async yield when needed, without having to manually wrap each async in a block_on (feels ugly).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can `spawn()` the whole thing, and `spawn_blocking()` for each blocking chunk:

```rust
async fn handle_request(data: &Bytes) {
    let mut tasks = vec![];
    for i in 0..1000 {
        tasks.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
            let processed =
                tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || do_heavy_calc_that_might_block(data, i)).await;
            let result = do_something_with_res(processed).await;
            result
        }));
    }
    let results = futures_util::future::join_all(tasks).await;
    results
}
```

However, beware that you may not need to use `spawn()` at all: if `do_somethine_with_res()` is I/O bound, just `join_all()` will give you what you want:

```rust
async fn handle_request(data: &Bytes) {
    let mut tasks = vec![];
    for i in 0..1000 {
        tasks.push(async move {
            let processed =
                tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || do_heavy_calc_that_might_block(data, i)).await;
            let result = do_something_with_res(processed).await;
            result
        });
    }
    let results = futures_util::future::join_all(tasks).await;
    results
}
```

Comment: You cannot put an async call inside the `spawn_blocking` closure...

Comment: @jaques-sam `do_heavy_calc_that_might_block()` is not async in the question.

Comment: But it is in your answer ;-)

Comment: @jaques-sam No it is not, `spawn_blocking()` is (which it always does).

Comment: Check this line: (your answer doesn't lie)  `tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || do_heavy_calc_that_might_block(data, i)).await;` --> that doesn't compile!

Comment: @jaques-sam The code does not compiler for marginal, unrelated reasons. If you fix them it compiles: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6e7dbb0eaa8a9aca15a319c7fb07aa6e.